# How to convert a .json file to an array

Tags: php, json

For the website that I'm making right now, I need to convert a .json file to an array in PHP.
Could anyone help me, because I've tried to do it, but something went wrong. Could you please check my code for any errors or improve it so that it does work?

```
function getData() {
    $json = "";
    $file=fopen("data/data.json","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $json .= fgets($file);
    }
    fclose($file);

    $data = json_decode($json);
    return $data;
}
```

An example of the .json contents :

```
{
    "dashboard": {
        "title": "Dashboard",
        "href": "/dashboard",
    },
    "settings": {
        "title": "Settings",
        "href": "/settings",
    }
}
```

Edit 1: Added example of the json file contents

Comment: Could you post an example of the contents of the file?

Comment: Your code looks OK, but wouldn't `file_get_contents` be simpler than your loop?

Comment: _something went wrong_. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Barmar it just doesnt work, I tried accessing the data, but somehow the array is empty.

Comment: If json_decode chokes on the json it will return 'null', but if you're seeing an empty array I'm not sure what's up.  But try runing your json through a linter to make sure it's valid.

Comment: @JamesAlday Thank You!!! That fixed it. My json wasnt valid. I've found what was wrong and fixed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file is invalid, it has extra commas after the last element of each object. It should be:

```
{
    "dashboard": {
        "title": "Dashboard",
        "href": "/dashboard"
    },
    "settings": {
        "title": "Settings",
        "href": "/settings"
    }
}
```

Also, you should specify the second argument `true` when you call `json_decode`, so you'll get an associative array rather than an object as the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = file_get_contents("data/data.json");
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

https://www.php.net/json_decode
The second parameter indicates you want it as an array instead of an object (the default)

You should also use json_last_error() to check for errors with json_decode()
https://www.php.net/function.json_last_error